# How to use NavControl in Http Interceptor in IONIC 3?

Tags: ionic3

I want to redirect to login page on http request 401 errors. How do I implement this in IONIC 3. Since IONIC 3 using Angular 4, that's why I can't use any service in HTTP Interceptor.

Answer (score 6):

well you can do it this way.

```
@Injectable()

export class Httpinterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private _inProgressCount = 0;

    constructor(private event: Events) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authReq = req.clone();
        return next
            .handle(authReq)
            .do((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    //HTTP Response
                }
            }, (err: any) => {
                /* HTTP ERRORRESPONSE goes here */ 
                // you can catch your http error here

                if (err.status == 401) {
                    this.event.publish('UNAUTHORIZED'); // catch the published event in app.component.ts where you define your rootPage.
                }
            });
    }
}
```

now, catch event in your `app.component.ts`.

```
this.event.subscribe('UNAUTHORIZED', () => {
    if (this.rootPage != LoginComponent) {
        this.rootPage = LoginComponent;
    }
});
```

you can also do that other way like importing appCtrl.

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNavs()[0].setRoot(LoginComponent)
```